# Is there any way of calling a function to erease all files before uploading new ones with multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob, multer

I'm trying to pass a function `ereaseFiles()` before the `upload.array()` method is called but I can't figure out how to make it.

The main goal is with a put request to delete all files on disk related to that object before of uploading new ones.

I've tried to set the function in the `diskStorage` section as well as in the callback of the put route. I even tried handling it in the function itself before the `upload.array()` method was called. I've tried working with promises but that is way too hard for me.

```
//function to be called (this works)
function ereaseFiles(req) {
    glob("uploads/" + req.body.numeroScheda + "*", function (err, files) {
        for (const file of files) {
            fs.unlink(file, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('successfully deleted files');
            });
        }
    });
}

//My multer setup:

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');

    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, req.body.numeroScheda + "-" + file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage, limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2,
    },
});

//MY EDIT PUT ROUTE
app.put("/immobili/:_id", upload.array('immaginePrincipale', 30), function (req, res) {

    const requestedId = req.params._id;
    const proprietaImmagini = req.files;
    const immagini = proprietaImmagini.map(function (immagine) {
        //console.log(immagine.path);
        return immagine.path;
    });

    Immobile.findOneAndUpdate(requestedId, {
        numeroScheda: req.body.numeroScheda,
        categoria: req.body.categoria,
        titolo: req.body.titolo,
        sottotitolo: req.body.sottotitolo,
        descrizione: req.body.descrizione,
        localita: req.body.localita,
        locali: req.body.locali,
        superficie: req.body.superficie,
        camere: req.body.camere,
        bagni: req.body.bagni,
        immagini: immagini,
    }, function (err, updatedImmobile) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        res.redirect("/immobili/" + requestedId);
    });
});
```

What should happen is that all files on disk associated with the object (`numeroScheda`) get deleted before the new ones are uploaded to keep the storage of files automated and clean.

EDIT 1:

I've created a delete route that works:

```
app.delete("/immobili/:_id", (req, res) => {

    const requestedId = req.params._id;

    Immobile.findOne({ _id: requestedId }, function (err, immobile) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        ereaseFiles(immobile);
    });

    Immobile.findOneAndRemove(requestedId, err => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else res.redirect('/immobili');
    });
});
```

the function `ereaseFiles` looks now like this:

```
ereaseFiles = immobile => {
    glob("uploads/" + immobile.numeroScheda + "*", function (err, files) {
        for (const file of files) {
            fs.unlink(file, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
    });
cancellato = true;
}
```

I've tried to implement this in the edit route with the middleware as kindly suggested with this:

```
app.use("/immobili/:_id", function (req, res, next) {
    const requestedId = req.params._id;

    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        Immobile.findOne({ _id: requestedId }, (err, immobile) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            ereaseFiles(immobile);
            console.log(this.cancellato);
            if (this.cancellato) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                next();
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

This works if the uploaded pictures are more or same than before but if less it outputs with strange behaviors (sometimes it uploads some pictures, sometimes none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won! The solution was to put a little timer on the `next()` function as it was firing too soon and the uploads and it was mixing the two. Thanks for your help everyone!

I've also added an `ereased` variable that turned off and on as the function completes. Thanks to Mr. Web for that.

Here's the answer if someone runs across this, there's some Italian in the code, hopefully is readable enough anyways!

```
cancellaFoto = immobile => {
    cancellato = false;
    glob("uploads/" + immobile.numeroScheda + "*", function (err, files) {
        for (const file of files) {
            fs.unlink(file, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
    });
    cancellato = true;
}

app.use("/immobili/:_id", function (req, res, next) {

    const requestedId = req.params._id;

    Immobile.findOne({ _id: requestedId }, (err, immobile) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        immobile.immagini = [];
        cancellaFoto(immobile);
        console.log(immobile.immagini);
        if (this.cancellato) {
            console.log(this.cancellato);
            return setTimeout(next, 500);
        } else {
            return console.log("Aborted");
        }
    });
});

//EDIT PUT ROUTE
app.put("/immobili/:_id", upload.array('immaginePrincipale', 30), function (req, res) {

    const requestedId = req.params._id;

    const proprietaImmagini = req.files;
    const immagini = proprietaImmagini.map(function (immagine) {
        //console.log(immagine.path);
        return immagine.path;
    });
    console.log(immagini);
    Immobile.findOneAndUpdate(requestedId, {
        numeroScheda: req.body.numeroScheda,
        categoria: req.body.categoria,
        titolo: req.body.titolo,
        sottotitolo: req.body.sottotitolo,
        descrizione: req.body.descrizione,
        localita: req.body.localita,
        locali: req.body.locali,
        superficie: req.body.superficie,
        camere: req.body.camere,
        bagni: req.body.bagni,
        immagini: immagini,
    }, function (err, updatedImmobile) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        res.redirect("/immobili/" + requestedId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware for that. Just make sure that the middleware is positioned before your put request handler.

```
app.use("/immobili/:_id", function(req,res,next){
eraseFiles(req);
let timer = setInterval(() => {
if(erased){
clearInterval(timer);
next();    
}
},100);

})

app.put("/immobili/:_id", upload.array('immaginePrincipale', 30), function (req, res) { ...
```

EDIT 1:

Please change your eraseFiles function to:

```
function ereaseFiles(req) {
glob("uploads/" + req.body.numeroScheda + "*", function (err, files) {
    for (let i=0;i<files.length-1;i++) {
        fs.unlink(files[i], err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('successfully deleted files');
            if(i===files.length-1)
             erased = true;
        });
    }
});
}
```

Edit 2: Changed a lot of things. Now the approach is your route will go to the middleware first. Your eraseFiles function will be called. While the erased variable is not true, your put route will not be hit. When the erasedFiles function is complete it will set erased to true. For this to work, you'll have to set erased=false in the file before all this.

Comment: I've tried this out, unfortunately the log of the function I've inserted on the files parameter returns an empty array, so the function does not work!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo the approach of @DEVCNN could work, but his `ereaseFiles` function looks wrong because `return glob` is not returning a Promise and the `await eraseFiles(req);`  in the middle-ware is not working correctly. Try to change `ereaseFiles` to return a Promise which is resolved in the `glob` callback

Comment: I didn't what glob does. But that's what i meant by adding that return.

Comment: The function works correctly if called in the route, it just needs to be called before other files are uploaded!

Comment: Update: I've added a complete delete route that works perfectly. I will now try to implement this in the edit route as well!

Comment: I've tried the edits solution, it returns "erased is not defined"

Comment: Is not defined because you should initiate it at the beginning of eraseFiles() to a false, it will turn true of it matches with the last if

Comment: There are a lot of cases that you need to handle here. I just tried to show you how you can do it. Firstly, erased should be declared in the global. You should define erased = false at the start in eraseFiles function. You should put a check if there are no files set erased to true and call next();. I hoped you would figure these things out. Anyway, Let us know if you got it working.

Comment: There are a lot of cases that you need to handle here. I just tried to show you how you can do it. Firstly, erased should be declared in the global. You should define erased = false at the start in eraseFiles function. You should put a check if there are no files set erased to true and call next();. I hoped you would figure these things out. Anyway, Let us know if you got it working.